# How can I anchor a DateTime to the X coordinate on an ASP Column Chart by properly converting it to a Double?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, charts, sqldatareader

I am attempting to anchor a DateTime object to the X coordinate of an ASP Column Chart, so that I can display line annotations on the columns when the chart is initialized. I understand that it needs to be a Double for this to work, and I have tried using DateTime.Now.ToOADate() as well as ToDouble() and the DateTime.Ticks property, but none of them have worked.

Here is my code (**MainForm.aspx.cs**):

```
    void getChartData()
    {
        String ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            String SQLText = "select AvailDate,MW from MWAvailability2 where UnitName = @UnitName and Station = @StationName and AvailDate between @AvailFrom and @AvailTo";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLText, connection);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitName", ddUnit.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StationName", ddStation.SelectedValue);
            if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length > 0)
                {    
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailFrom", TextBoxFrom.Text);
                }
            else
                {    
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailFrom", "01-01-1900");
                }
            if (TextBoxTo.Text.Length > 0)
                {   
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailTo", TextBoxTo.Text);
                }
            else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailTo", "01-01-2050");
                }

            if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length > 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length > 0)   // Text in from, text in to
            {
                chartTitle.Text = "Station " + ddStation.SelectedValue + " " + ddUnit.SelectedValue + " From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;
            }
            else if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length > 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length == 0)     // Text in from, no text in to
            {
                chartTitle.Text = "Station " + ddStation.SelectedValue + " " + ddUnit.SelectedValue + " From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: 01/01/2050";
            }
            else if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length == 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length > 0)     // No text in from, text in to
            {
                chartTitle.Text = "Station " + ddStation.SelectedValue + " " + ddUnit.SelectedValue + " From: 01/01/1900 " + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;
            }
            else if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length == 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length == 0)     // No text in from, no text in to
            {
                chartTitle.Text = "Station " + ddStation.SelectedValue + " " + ddUnit.SelectedValue + " From: 01/01/1900 To: 01/01/2050";
            }



            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Series series = ColumnChart.Series["Series1"];

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {

                   series.Points.AddXY(reader["AvailDate"].ToString(), reader["MW"]);

                    TextAnnotation ta = new TextAnnotation();

                    ta.AnchorX = Convert.ToDouble(reader["AvailDate"]); // problem
                    ta.AnchorY = Convert.ToDouble(reader["MW"]);

                    ta.Text = "Station A";
                    ColumnChart.Annotations.Add(ta);




                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

When the line that is supposed to anchor the text annotation to the X coordinate says `ta.AnchorX = Convert.ToDouble(reader["AvailDate"]);`, I get an error message that says "Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Double'." When I change it to `ta.AnchorX = Convert.ToDouble(reader["AvailDate"].ToString());`, the error tells me "Input string was not in a correct format."

If it helps, here is the code for the **HomePage.aspx.cs**, where it was apparently less complicated to do this conversion:

```
     void getChartData()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // Read the data from XML file into DataSet
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/MWAvailability2.xml"));
        // Specify the column that contains values for X-AXIS
        ColumnChart.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "AvailDate";
        // Specify the column that contains values for Y-AXIS
        ColumnChart.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "MW";
        // Annotations?
        TextAnnotation ta = new TextAnnotation();
        var xv = Convert.ToDouble("AvailDate");
        var yv = Convert.ToDouble("MW");

        ta.AnchorX = xv;
        ta.AnchorY = yv;

        ta.Text = "Station A";
        ColumnChart.Annotations.Add(ta);


        // Set DataSet as the DataSource for the Chart control
        ColumnChart.DataSource = ds;
        // Finally call DataBind
        ColumnChart.DataBind();
    }
```

I believe that the error most likely has something to do with the SQL reader object, but I am not sure. I have tried other solutions from similar questions on here, some of which are listed above, but none of them seem to apply to my situation.

I am happy to provide any other information I may have omitted that might help better explain my situation. Any advice or suggestions that could help me figure this out would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to focus on your problem line primarily and it should lead you in the correct direction...

```
ta.AnchorX = Convert.ToDouble(reader["AvailDate"]); // problem
```

The problem here is that you are not supplying a `DateTime` value. The `SqlReader` class always supplies back objects when using an indexer, meaning you are actually invoking the constructor `Convert.ToDouble(object)` not `Convert.ToDouble(DateTime)`. The `Convert` class is suppressing the compiler error because there is a match for the method call, but not the one you are expecting. You can confirm this by attempting to assign the variable `AnchorX` directly with `reader["AvailDate"]`. It will tell you the cast is invalid as an object cannot be stored in a more derived type without an explicit cast. Same goes for if you append `ToString()` to `reader(["AvailDate"])` this would invoke `Convert.ToDouble(String)`. If the type stored in the SQL database is indeed that of `Date` or `DateTime` then you may simply specify a cast.

Try this:

```
ta.AnchorX = Convert.ToDouble((DateTime)reader["AvailDate"]); // solution?
```

**Update**

@Quantic brought to my attention that an InvalidCastException is still thrown, while the cast is still necessary as my original assumption stands it will fail at runtime. Further inspecting MSDN Convert.ToDouble(DateTime) is not supported and will fail:

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Double
>   This conversion is not supported. No value is returned.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfdd1sd9(v=vs.110).aspx

The correct call would indeed be...

```
ta.AnchorX = ((DateTime)reader["AvailDate"]).ToOADate();
```

Comment: That won't convert. You could use the [`ToOADate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx) method which returns a double, "the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899", and appears to have a resolution of an hour (maybe better):  `ta.AnchorX = ((DateTime)reader["AvailDate"]).ToOADate();`.

Comment: @Quantic Thank you for pointing this out, I updated my answer and upvoted your comment!

Comment: Thank you. Well I tried that and it rendered the chart, but it just displays as normal with no line annotations which I had hoped to accomplish by anchoring the X coord. Do I need to edit the HomePage.aspx.cs as well? Or simply switch the order of the statements around?